# NCache - Failed to start my cache . ErrorL Specified cache is not registered

Tags: ncache

I am trying to use the NCache Open Source. I already installed it in my local machine. I already edited the config.ncconf file as instructed. Already restarted the service by using Restart-Service command.

```
<cache-config cache-name="myreplicatedcache">
<cache-settings inproc="False">
 <logging enable-logs="True" trace-errors="True" trace-debug="False" log-path=""/>
 <performance-counters enable-counters="True" snmp-port="0"/>
 <cache-notifications item-remove="False" item-add="False" item-update="False"/>
 <cleanup interval="15sec"/>
 <storage type="heap" cache-size="1024mb"/>
 <eviction-policy default-priority="normal" eviction-ratio="5%"/>
 <cache-topology topology="replicated">
   <cluster-settings operation-timeout="60sec" 
       stats-repl-interval="600sec" use-heart-beat="False">
     <cluster-connection-settings port-range="1" connection-retries="2" 
                   connection-retry-interval="10secs" cluster-port="7804"/>
   </cluster-settings>
 </cache-topology>
 <client-death-detection enable="False" grace-interval="60sec"/>
</cache-settings>
<cache-deployment>
 <servers>
   <server-node ip="192.168.0.101"/>
 </servers>
</cache-deployment>
</cache-config>
```

Still, I cannot start the new cache that I registered. I encountered - "Specified cache is not registered". I am not sure why it's happening for I am sure it is registered. Here is what it looks like:

[image: NCache Start Cache]

Answer (score 0):

Are the ports open and allows traffic? You can try by shutting down the windows firewall and if that works, define rules to allow traffic.

also you can try with partitioned cache configuration

```
<cache-config cache-name="myPartitionedCache" alias="" config-id="44fb997a-f6a7-433b-9439-7ef9de9f47c7" config-version="0">
    <cache-settings inproc="False">
      <logging enable-logs="True" trace-errors="True" trace-debug="False" log-path=""/>
      <performance-counters enable-counters="True" snmp-port="0"/>
      <cache-notifications item-remove="False" item-add="False" item-update="False"/>
      <cleanup interval="15sec"/>
      <storage type="heap" cache-size="1024mb"/>
      <eviction-policy default-priority="normal" eviction-ratio="5%"/>
      <cache-topology topology="partitioned">
        <cluster-settings operation-timeout="60sec" stats-repl-interval="60sec" use-heart-beat="False">
          <cluster-connection-settings port-range="1" connection-retries="2" connection-retry-interval="2secs" cluster-port="7801"/>
        </cluster-settings>
      </cache-topology>
      <client-death-detection enable="False" grace-interval="60sec"/>
    </cache-settings>
    <cache-deployment>
      <servers>
        <server-node ip="yourIPHere"/>

      </servers>
    </cache-deployment>
  </cache-config>
```